# OpenSSL - Encrypt plain text using RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256

Tags: encryption, openssl

I want to encrypt local plain text file using openssl and RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256 algorithm.
I tried to use the same approach with this blog entry but it did not work.
https://europatech.co.uk/encryption-decryption-with-kms-and-openssl/

```
$ echo "hello" > plaintext.txt
$ openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 \
  -in plaintext.txt -pubin -inkey pubkey.pem -out plaintext.bin
-pkeyopt command before -inkey
Usage: pkeyutl [options]
-in file        input file
-out file       output file
-sigfile file signature file (verify operation only)
-inkey file     input key
-keyform arg    private key format - default PEM
-pubin          input is a public key
-certin         input is a certificate carrying a public key
-pkeyopt X:Y    public key options
-sign           sign with private key
-verify         verify with public key
-verifyrecover  verify with public key, recover original data
-encrypt        encrypt with public key
-decrypt        decrypt with private key
-derive         derive shared secret
-hexdump        hex dump output
-passin arg     pass phrase source
```

am I missing something?

Comment: what happens if you put the `-pkeyopt` options **after** the `-inkey` option?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: the linked article describes a **hybrid encryption scheme**, meaning that you encrypt the plaintext file in the first step with a symmetric algorithm like "AES-CBC-256". For this you have to generate a random encryption key. This key is encrypted in the second step using an asymmetric algorithm like "RSA OAEP SHA256)" and a public key you received from the recipient. In the end you send the encrypted key together with ther ciphertext file to the recipient who decrypts in the first step the key and then the ciphertext.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same openssl command and this worked for me:

```
openssl pkeyutl -in data.txt -encrypt -pubin -inkey Oaep_Pub_Rsa.pem -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha256 -out enc.pem
```